# How can I convert the data from an API url into an array in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

How can I take the data from this URL and convert it into an array to later scramble the letters of each word?

This is how I am fetching the data from the URL but I can't seem to turn it into an array.

I have tried many ways of fetching data but this seems to be the only way which is working for me with this URL.

Once I am able to turn it into an array I need to split each letter into an array to scramble all the letters of each word without affecting the first or last letter of each.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {


constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    data:false
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  let url = 'https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/sentences/1';
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    result.json().then((resp)=>{

      this.setState({data:resp})
    })
  })

}

  render() {
    const data=this.state.data;

    console.warn('data');
    return (
     <div>
       {
        data ?
         <div>
           <h1 className="title">{data.data.sentence}</h1>
           {/* <h3 className="subheading">Guess the sentence!</h3>
           <h3 className="subheading">The yellow blocks are meant for spaces</h3>
           <h1 className="score">Score: 0</h1> */}
         </div>
         : <h1>Please wait...</h1>
       }
     </div>
  )}
  
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you tryed `this.setState({data:JSON.parse(resp.data.sentence)})`  then you transform the state value into an array in the renderer with a combination of `split(" ")` and `Array.from()` ?

Comment: What is the shape of `resp` that you're calling `setState` with?

Answer (score 0):

```js
result.json().then((resp) => {
  // resp is: {"data":{"sentence":"I love learning code"}}
  const { data } = resp
  this.setState({ data })
})
```

then later in your code: `const letters = Array.from(data.sentence)`